# Group array based on n keys of objectd

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

What is the most efficient way and approach to group an array of n objects based on n keys or nested keys?

```
const data = [,
    {a: 1, b: 2, c:3},
    {d: 4, e: 5, f: 6},
    {a: 1, b: 2, c:3},
    {g: 7, h: 8, i: 9},
    {d: 4, e: 5, f: 6},
    {g: 7, h: 8, i: 9},
 ];
```

into something like

```
const grouped = [
 [
    {a: 1, b: 2, c:3},
    {a: 1, b: 2, c:3},
 ],
 [
    {d: 4, e: 5, f: 6},
    {d: 4, e: 5, f: 6},
 ],
 [
    {g: 7, h: 8, i: 9},
    {g: 7, h: 8, i: 9},
 ],
]
```

Comment: right. what have you tried? do you have always same keys or do you have somtimes more keys who no affect grouping?

Comment: How much data are you sifting through?

Comment: `{a: 1, b: 2, c:3}` and  `{a: 1, b: 2, c:4}` should be in the same group?

Comment: How do you know which group an item goes in? It has to be an exact match of the other items in the group?

Comment: @NinaScholz sometimes I have more keys which should not be affected by grouping. I have tried to reduce and create a new array based on the keys that I need.

Comment: @EhsanNazeri only if I want to group by key a and key b

Comment: how do you know which keys are relvant?

Comment: @NinaScholz by passing it into a an algorithm.

Comment: do you have an example for the above?

Comment: @NinaScholz gorupBy([a,b,c]) is quite good and semms generic for n keys

Comment: @JacobSchneider 10+ objects. Not more than 50.

Comment: what about the other objects with different keys for grouping?

Comment: @NinaScholz, in my scenario, the other objects can have n keys. The script should only group by the given keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
{ d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 },
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
{ g: 7, h: 8, i: 9 },
{ d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 },
{ g: 7, h: 8, i: 9 },
```

];

function groupObjectByKey(data) {

```
var groupData = {}

const getKeys = (value) => Object.keys(value);

const groupKey = (keys) => keys.join(",");

data.forEach(value => {
    let key = groupKey(getKeys(value));
    if (groupData[key])
        groupData[key].push(value)
    else
        groupData[key] = [value];
})

return Object.values(groupData);
```

}

let result = groupObjectByKey(data);
console.log(result)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is:

- use a lookup table to store objects of the same identity
- the identity for each object we use here is its unique key, in my solution below, it is the concatenated string of that object's pairs of key-value
- remember to sort the object's keys alphabetically, to handle the case of `{a:1, b:2, c:3}` and `{b:2, a:1, c:3}` - which is basically the same

The the worst-case time complexity of this approach is ***O(nm)*** (with `n` is the length of the `data` array, and `m` the length of the object's keys)

Below snippet demonstrates the idea

```js
const lookup = {}

const data = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { b: 2, a: 1, c: 3 },
  { d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 },
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { g: 7, h: 8, i: 9 },
  { d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 },
  { g: 7, h: 8, i: 9 },
]

data.forEach((obj) => {
  const uniqueKey = Object.keys(obj)
    .sort()
    .map((k) => `${k}${obj[k]}`)
    .join("-")

  if (lookup[uniqueKey] !== undefined) {
    lookup[uniqueKey].push(obj)
  } else {
    lookup[uniqueKey] = [obj]
  }
})

const res = Object.values(lookup)
console.log(res)
```